# How to exclude or ignore a folder from tree command

Tags: windows-10, command-line, tree-view

I am using `tree` command in *Windows Command Prompt*, to view tree structure of a NodeJS project folder. I want to ignore a folder name `node_modules` as it contains folders and files I don't want to see for now.

```
E:\Project\Nodejs\Project3 - TDD>tree /?
Graphically displays the folder structure of a drive or path.

TREE [drive:][path] [/F] [/A]

   /F   Display the names of the files in each folder.
   /A   Use ASCII instead of extended characters.
```

I couldn't find any attributes for help. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: As e.g. `%APPDATA%` is excluded it might be sufficient to mark the folder as hidden or system.